# Fatal Python error: PyMUTEX_LOCK(_PyRuntime.ceval.gil.mutex) failed

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am testing `pybind11`

in my `cpplcm.py`

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int greatest_common_divisor(int x, int y) {
  int r, tmp;
  if(x < y){
    tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
  }

  r= x % y;
  while(r != 0){
    x = y;
    y = r;
    r = x % y;
  }
  return y;
}


int least_common_multiple(int x, int y) {
  return x * y / greatest_common_divisor(x, y);
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(cpplcm, m) {
  m.doc() = "pybind11 example";
  m.def("greatest_common_divisor", &greatest_common_divisor, "A function which calculate greatest common divisor");
  m.def("least_common_multiple", &least_common_multiple, "");
}
```

I compiled this and made `cpplcm.cpython-37m-darwin.so`

```
$g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC `python -m pybind11 --includes` cpplcm.cpp -o cpplcm`python3-config --extension-suffix` -lpython3.7m
```

then in test.py in the same directory

```
import cpplcm
```

it stops and shows the error

`Fatal Python error: PyMUTEX_LOCK(_PyRuntime.ceval.gil.mutex) failed`

It might be some memory problem ???

Any suggestion to solve helps thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your OS must be MacOS, so you can try:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall **-Xlinker -undefined -Xlinker dynamic_lookup -flto=thin** -std=c++11 -fPIC `python -m pybind11 --includes cpplcm.cpp` -o cpplcm `python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

Comment: This solved it for me! Altough I use -dynamiclib as a linker option and -flto=thin do not seem needed. Still thanks for the pointer.